# How to add TXT dns record for configure Opendkim

Tags: dns, postfix-mta

I need to send e-mails from my virtual server, the problem is that the e-mail containing links comes to be considered as junk! But I need to insert links in my e-mails.
So I have installed Postfix, configured it for send e-mails using my SMTP mailbox, then I am trying to configure OpenDkim for signing my e-mails.  I have done all the steps correctly except one: adding TXT DNS record!
I have read this guide: https://syslog.tv/2010/01/11/dkim-on-debian-with-postfix/.
We have to add these 2 txt dns records:

```
_domainkey.DOMAIN.TLD. IN TXT "t=y; o=-;"
SELECTOR._domainkey.DOMAIN.TLD. IN TXT "k=rsa; t=y; p=YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE"
```

But I don't understand HOW I can add this records... in my DNS control panel I must specify for each new DNS record at least 3 fields: the type is for sure TXT, ok, but what are the name of the record, and the value of the record?
I have tried to add the first as follow:

```
Name: _domainkey.mydomain.example.
Type: TXT
Value: t=y; o=-;
```

But I receive an error message that tells me that it is not possible to add a subdomain? Then I have tried to reverse the fields/value:

```
Name: t=y; o=-;
Type: TXT
Value: _domainkey.mydomain.example.
```

But this time I will not see any type of message/error from my control panel, so I don't understand if there is a problem in it or something else?

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the dns like this

Name: selector._domainkey
Type: TXT
Value:k=rsa; t=y; p=YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE

NOTE:the selector means the selector you are used to create opendkim